# ¿Alguno(a) acá sabe si existe algo similar al Timer y el TimerTask en C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto para la universidad en C++ y sería de mucha utilidad algo similar a un TimerTask de Java, pero no encuentro nada que se asemeje.
La idea es en un minimalista videojuego tener un ciclo que incremente un entero, una vez cada segundo y que evalúe cuando el entero llegó a X valor y entonces ejecuta una X acción y luego lo reinicia o algo por el estilo. Era una técnica que usaba en Java para crear pequeños retrasos en algunos juegos sin recurrir a pausar hilos, pero no estoy muy seguro de si en C++ existe alguna herramienta que permita hacer algo similar.

Comment: Escribir en [es.so] es gratis. ¿Por qué no pruebas a detallar un poco más tu pregunta para entender qué es exactamente lo que necesitas? ¿Gestión de hilos? ¿Lanzamiento de señales? ¿Un simple cronómetro tal vez? También sería interesante que te pasases por el [tour] y por [ask] para entender el funcionamiento de este portal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <functional>

class Timer
{
public:
  Timer(std::function<void(void)> func, unsigned int interval)
    : _thread
      {
        [func, interval]()
        { 
          while (true)
          { 
            auto x = std::chrono::steady_clock::now()
                   + std::chrono::milliseconds(interval);
            func();
            std::this_thread::sleep_until(x);
          }
        }
      }
  {
    _thread.detach();
  }
private:
  std::thread _thread;
};

int main()
{
  bool exit = false;
  auto lambda = [counter=0, &exit]() mutable
  {
    counter++;
    if(counter == 10)
    {
      exit = true;
      std::cout << "counter=" << counter;
    }
  };

  Timer timer(lambda , 1000);

  while( !exit );
}
```

La clase `Timer` es el temporizador en sí mismo. Esta clase crea un hilo a nivel interno para ejecutar una tarea de forma asíncrona. La tarea a ejecutar se le pasa via functor, al igual que el intervalo de ejecución.

A continuación creamos una función lambda que inicializa una variable interna `counter` cada vez que se le llama. Cuando el contador llega a 10 actualiza la variable `exit` que motiva la finalización del programa.

Las posibilidades son infinitas.